# How to combine multiple last columns in Tableau?

Tags: math, visualization, tableau-api, tableau-desktop, tableau-prep

Please help me!!!! So basically what I want to do is I want the Sum, average, minimum, and maximum for each column. It is only letting me chose 1 option, how do I pick all the options shown? Is that even possible?[Image of Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5TdY.jpg)

I tried using ChatGPT to figure out formulas but none of those formulas would work anyways.